# Complex manifold with no divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I read in Griffith Harris P132 that a complex manifold of dimension greater than one can have no divisors on it at all. I want to find examples. Is there an example? Does the Hopf manifolds $S^1\times S^{2n-1}$ have such properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you want, as mentioned in the comments, is that of an Inoue surface. Since they have no curves, they cannot have any divisors. On the other hand, consider the Hopf surface $S$ given by $(\mathbb{C}^2-{0})/\sim$ where $(x,y) \sim (2^nx,2^ny)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and the morphism $\varphi:S\to\mathbb{P}^{1}$ given by $[(x,y)] \mapsto [x:y]$. The pull back of a point $y\in\mathbb{P}^1$ will be a divisor on $S$. In fact, since $\varphi$ induces an elliptic fibration,  the divisors are just elliptic curves. To finish, one can show that these are all the divisors on $S$, which establishes $\text{Cl}(S) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=2$ there is a nontrivial picard group. There are a few decent references about this listed on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_surface) page for Hopf surfaces.

Comment: Thanks, but I still cannot understand why a complex manifold can havd no divisors. Does the non-trival picard group in the answer imply it?

Comment: I think this is the source you want for the Hopf Manifolds: http://www.pnas.org/content/55/2/240.full.pdf+html   (see theorem 2)

Comment: This one shows that there is a curve on it.

Comment: On the other hand, there are things called inuoue surfaces which apparently have no closed complex subvarieties. See this overflow question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88996/non-compact-complex-surfaces-which-are-not-kahler and the comment to the first response there